# Perfect square python program doesn't return expected outcome

Tags: python

When I use a number that is obviously not a perfect square it still returns saying it is, I have looked for ages for a solution but no luck here is the code:

```
try:
    while True:
        test_cases = int(input('How many test cases will you run, maximum of 30? '))#the ammount of test cases the user wants
        if test_cases >= 30: #exceeding the amount of test cases asked for in the specification
            print('Too high')
            pass
        else:
            break
except ValueError:#if the data entered isnt an integer
        print('Wrong data type')
        pass#re-run the try statement

x = 0
for x in range(test_cases):#loop runs for the amount of test cases the user wanted
    try:
        while True:
            tested_number = input('What number do you want to test, maximum is 10000? ')
            if int(tested_number) >= 10000:
                print('Number too large')
                pass
            else:
                break
    except ValueError:
        print(tested_number, 'is not an integer')

    if tested_number[-1] == ('2', '3', '7', '8'):#take the last element of the string and checks if it is equal to one of the values in the brackets
        print(tested_number, 'is not a perfect square')
        break
    y = 0   
    sum_of_number = sum(int(y) for y in tested_number)#the sum of all the number in the list, highest is 36 due to 10000 limit
    if sum_of_number > 9:
        sum_of_number = str(sum_of_number)
        digital_root = sum_of_number[0] + sum_of_number[1]
        if digital_root == (2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9):
            print(tested_number, 'is not a perfect square')
            break
        else:
            print(tested_number, 'is a perfect square')
    elif sum_of_number == (2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9):
        print(tested_number, 'is not a perfect square')
    else:
        print(tested_number, 'is a perfect square')
```

I know there is quite a lot to look at but I honestly can't find the solution and I have no idea where the program begins to fail. Thank you for any help that can be given.

Comment: Change `if digital_root == (2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9):` to `if digital_root in (2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9):`

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the operator for testing equality: "==" - with the operator for testing membership of a group "in".

So the three lines like

```
if foo == (1, 2, 3):
```

should be

```
if foo in (1, 2, 3):
```

Changing these lines should make your tests effective.

Comment: Thank you so much, bad mistake on my behalf, the program now works